# How to change parameter value in query dialog Jaspersoft?

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports

To run my report I need to set parameter $P{P_CLIENT_TYPE} to one of three strings: "Insured" , "Policy Holder" or "BOTH". I would like to use shorter versions: "INS", "PH" and "%".

How to convert later these 3 short parameters in my query dialog, so instead of "PH" it will know that it means "Insured"?

My query looks like below:

```
select distinct  (SELECT MIN(INS_FROM)
FROM [dbo].[INSURANCE_DB]
where [CLIENT_TYPE] like $P{P_CLIENT_TYPE}
  and code_type =$P{P_CODE_TYPE}
  and code = $P{P_COD}
) MIN_INS_FROM
,IIF( x.max1  > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) 
  ,DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
  , x.max1
) MAX_INS_TO
```

I tried to make replace function or convert function at the beginning of the query but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, it was quite simple. I just needed to use CASE WHEN ... THEN

```
select distinct  (SELECT MIN(INS_FROM)
FROM [dbo].[INSURANCE_DB]
  where [CLIENT_TYPE] like 
  **CASE
        WHEN $P{P_CLIENT_TYPE} = 'INS' THEN 'Insured' 
        WHEN $P{P_CLIENT_TYPE} = 'PH' THEN 'Policy Holder' 
        ELSE '%' 
   END**
  and code_type =$P{P_CODE_TYPE}
  and code = $P{P_COD}
) MIN_INS_FROM
,IIF( x.max1  > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) 
,DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
 , x.max1
) MAX_INS_TO
```